# 18.04 boot process hangs at purple screen after RTX 2060 install

Tags: boot, nvidia, gnome

I recently installed a new RTX 2060 in my Ubuntu machine. I had a bit of trouble installing it because I couldn't get the drivers to install from Nvidia's website. Then I found the appropriate ppa. This is after I had reinstalled the OS once. I have just reinstalled again because that install didn't go correctly because I didn't format things and just chose the automatic route. I did it the proper way this time and yet my system still hangs at boot. I have to go into recovery mode, select the dpkg repair option, and then everything boots up just fine.

I just want it to do that without me having to mess with things. From off to on with no touching, you know. Anyway here's some info about my system:

``````
                          ./+o+-       christopher@stormbreaker
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 25m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 1932
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.19
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 3840x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: GNOME Shell
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: McOS-MJV-Dark-mode-Gnome-3.30-1.1 [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Humanity-Dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Cantarell 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i7-4770K @ 8x 4.5GHz [27.8°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: GeForce RTX 2060
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 2512MiB / 23991MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

Everything was fine until I installed the new card. But that is not really pinpointing the issue. I don't really know why it's behaving this way. I was hoping someone out there had an idea about why it's doing that.

Thanks!